# Error: VHDL compiler exiting

Tags: vhdl

I am using modelsim. I wrote simple code but i am getting error.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;



entity clk_counter is
port(output    : out   bit;
     clk : in bit
   );
end clk_counter;

architecture rtl of clk_counter_arch is

    signal clock_counter_output_flag: bit;
    constant clock_max_count : integer := 20000;


begin

     process (clock_counter_output_flag, clk,CLK'event )

       variable clock_count : integer := 0; 
       --constant clock_max_count : integer := 20000;
       variable clock_out : bit := 0;
       -- wait until CLK'event and CLK='1';
          begin
              if (CLK'event and CLK='1') then
                  clock_count := clock_count+1;
                  if (clock_count = clock_max_count) then
                      clock_out := 1;
                   else
                       clock_out := 0;  
                  end if
               end if
               clock_counter_output_flag <= clock_out;        
          end process;


END Architecture;
```

Error messege:

```
 # ** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.clk_counter_arch.                    
 #                                                                         
 # ** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/work/src/clk_counter(13):              VHDL Compiler exiting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity name is clk_counter and you have defined architecture rtl of clk_counter_arch. Hence, you are getting error. Change clk_counter_arch to clk_counter.

Second, you should end architecture as end rtl.

Also, why are you using two additional variables clock_out and clock_counter_output_flag ? If you want that values as output of your code, you should simply write

```
if (CLK'event and CLK='1') then
                  clock_count := clock_count+1;
                  if (clock_count = clock_max_count) then
                      output<='1';
                   else
                       output <='0';  
                  end if;
               end if;
```

Comment: yeah, I just did it. before posting this question I should have examine the code properly. Anyways thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: Your first point is valid. 'Second, you should end architecture as end rtl.' This is style which you generally aren't successful enforcing on third parties. As far as the remaining coding style nitpicking you also point our the missing semicolon's following the `end if`s (also still present in your answer). The sensitivity list error and redundancy. The assignment of numeric literals to type bit (3 places).  The missing assignment (apparently) from `clock_counter_output_flag` to `output` in the original.

Comment: Its definitely good practice to point out all errors. But, as he has solved his problem, I did not edit my answer.